# Cannot access docker url in fastapi

Tags: docker, fastapi

I built a fastapi app when I run uvicorn immo.app:app everything works I can access the url http://127.0.0.1:8000/. The structure of my code:

project-name/
src/
immo/
app.py
tests/
DockerFile
docker-compose.yml
run.sh

I want to run it in docker So I created a DockerFile

```
FROM python:3.9.0-slim
EXPOSE 8000
WORKDIR /Workspace
COPY ./requirements.txt ./requirements.txt
RUN pip install --no-cache-dir --upgrade -r ./requirements.txt
COPY src/immo ./src/immo
COPY ./setup.cfg ./setup.cfg
COPY ./setup.py ./setup.py
RUN pip install -e .
CMD ["uvicorn", "immo.app:app", "--host", "0.0.0.0"]
```

And I have a docker-compose.yml

```
version: '3'
services:
  immo:
    build: .
    environment:
      - OPENAI_API_KEY=${OPENAI_API_KEY}
      - PINECONE_API_KEY=${PINECONE_API_KEY}
      - PINECONE_ENV=${PINECONE_ENV}
    ports:
      - "8000:8000"
    volumes:
    - ./data:/Workspace/data
```

And run.sh

```
docker-compose build
docker-compose run immo
```

When running run.sh the terminal shows the following

[image]

But the browser shows cannot reach the url. Can you help please thank you

Comment: Which URL are you trying to access? What does `curl` say if you try to make a request to that URL?

Comment: $ curl http://0.0.0.0:8000 and curl http://localhost:8000 show couldn't connect to server

Comment: When I copy /data in Dockerfile and running docker build -t <image-name> .
and docker run -p 8000:8000 -e VAR_NAME=VALUE <image-name> and providing envs manually it works

Comment: as I said executing run.sh It shows uvicorn running in http://0.0.0.0:8000 but not accessible. looking at docker ui I see no erros in terminal and the tab inspect shows I have all my envs